# Magento 2 Sample Data installation Error

Tags: magento2

After bin/magento sampledata:deploy;

i m trying to do  bin/magento  setup:upgrade; Following error thrown.

```
Unable to apply data patch Magento\GroupedProductSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallGroupedProductSampleData for module Magento_GroupedProductSampleData. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.
```

Magento Version is 2.3.4

Comment: Did you try anything from the doc? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data-other.html

Answer (score 0):

An issue like this occurred here and it was caused by wrong csv data. I changed data like [1] to [2]  (adding "" on the value) in the files [3] and [4]. If it not help, check logs in system.log.

1. `""value"":%url_key=watches%`
2. `""value"":""%url_key=watches%""`
3. `/vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data/fixtures/catalog_rules.csv`

4 `./vendor/magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data/fixtures/sales_rules.csv`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround rather than a solution:

1. Remove `magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data` from *composer.json*
2. Run `composer update magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data`
3. Rerun `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Your sample data won't include grouped products, but the setup will complete (unless there is a similar issue with another sample data module - in such case repeat the procedure above for that module).

Answer (score 0):

struggling through same error

Unable to apply data patch Magento\GroupedProductSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallGroupedProductSampleData for module Magento_GroupedProductSampleData. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly

Magento Version is 2.3.4-p1